# Windows 7 slow logging in with mobile phone connected

Tags: windows-7, usb

When I'm starting Windows (Win7 Pro 64) while my mobile phone (Samsung Galaxy I9100) is connected to the USB port it hangs for about 1-2 min (on the screen just after logging in).

I checked windows logs and found two critical errors connected with that issue :

1) A problem has occurred with one or more user-mode drivers and the hosting process has been terminated.  This may temporarily interrupt your ability to access the devices.

2) The device GT-I9100 (location Port_#0002.Hub_#0001) is offline due to a user-mode driver crash.  Windows will attempt to restart the device 5 more times.  Please contact the device manufacturer for more information about this problem.

I would be very greateful if anyone can provide me with the explanation: why that problem occures. I know that the best solutions is just to connect phone after logging in, but I'm just currious why is it happening. I lost few days just to figure out why my system is starting so slow even after reinstall.

Comment: It looks like a driver issue. Which driver version are you currently using?

Comment: Driver Provider: Microsoft, Driver Date: 2006-06-21, Driver Version: 6.1.7600.16385, Digital SIgner: Microsoft Windows

Comment: Try updating the driver with this newer version: http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/ScopedViewRedirect.aspx?updateid=aea37390-adff-47f6-9383-c01e45e0878b